# ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'makeDecorator'

Tags: angular, eonasdan-datetimepicker, ng-modules

I have been trying to use the ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker but not with much luck. Here's what's happening:

```
Z:\Dashboard>npm start

> dashboard@0.0.0 start Z:\Dashboard
> ng serve

** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200 **
Hash: 8c10d4427bac000e3cf8
Time: 14549ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 158 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 206 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 37.4 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 5.28 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in A2Edatetimepicker is not an NgModule
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

So then I open any file in my project, make no changes to the code, just put a space somewhere and save so that it re-compiles, and it works! But it won't `ng build`. When I try to build the project I get this error:

```
ERROR in Unexpected value 'A2Edatetimepicker in Z:/Dashboard/node_modules/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/dist/datetimepicker.module.d.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in Z:/Dashboard/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'Z:\Dashboard\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

in my Calendar Component:

```
import * as datetimepicker from 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js';
```

and my app.module.ts:

```
import { A2Edatetimepicker } from 'ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/dist/datetimepicker.module';

imports: [
  A2Edatetimepicker
]
```

That's the gist of it. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Test 1
Changes:

```
import { A2Edatetimepicker } from 'ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/dist/datetimepicker.module';
to
import { A2Edatetimepicker } from 'ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker';
```

New error:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol Injectable in Z:/Dashboard/node_modules/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/metadata.d.ts, resolving symbol OpaqueToken in Z:/Dashboard/node_modules/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/opaque_token.d.ts, resolving symbol OpaqueToken in Z:/Dashboard/node_modules/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/opaque_token.d.ts

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'Z:\Dashboard\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

NEW INFO:

I found that if I use `ng build --prod --aot false` I get a different error:

```
ERROR in A2Edatetimepicker is not an NgModule
```

Solution not found, but this works for now...
I changed:

```
import { A2Edatetimepicker } from 'ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/dist/datetimepicker.module';

imports: [
  A2Edatetimepicker
]
to

import { DateTimePickerDirective } from 'ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/dist/datetimepicker.directive.js';

declarations: [
  DateTimePickerDirective
]
```

and it worked but only with `ng build --prod --aot false`. I don't think that will do for the final build though. At least I can continue working on it for now. But this problem definitely remains. When I use `ng build --prod` I still get the error above:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'makeDecorator'...........
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/atais/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker scroll to bottom of doc, do you have to add the import to your `vendor.ts` file?

Comment: I don't appeard to have a vendor.ts file

Comment: change the import statement in your `app.module` to just `import {A2Edatetimepicker} from 'ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker';`

Comment: New error, posted above.

Comment: Also, now `A2Edatetimepicker` has red squiggly lines under it.

Comment: Saw this mentioned in a related post: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3706

Not sure if that helps, just throwing it out there...